# How to update GEF editor if file renamed?

Tags: eclipse-gef

How to update GEF editor if file renamed?

This works fine for text editors. For example in Eclipse go to Navigator, open file HelloWorld.java in editor, rename HelloWorld.java to HelloWorld2.java in Navigator. Note that editor is now updated and it titled "HelloWorld2.java".

To do that Eclipse creates listener and adds it to ITextEditor:
`IElementStateListener fElementStateListener= new ElementStateListener() (handles elementMoved and calles setInput((IEditorInput) movedElement))
ITextEditor.getDocumentProvider().addElementStateListener(fElementStateListener);`

I guess I need to do the same thing for in org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor but I don't know how cause graphicalEditor, doesn't have documentProvider.

**upd:**

There are three examples provided with GEF. One of them is Logic 
example: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Developer_FAQ#How_do_I_Run_the_Logic_Example.3F

In the LogicEditor class, there is inner class ResourceTracker which is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a resource listener and update your editor properties (i.e. title, tooltip) when you detect your resource was moved.

Comment: i'm not sure it should be done this way. In resourcelistener i don't have reference to editor, so I will need to scan for opened editors, also I will be notified to late in resourceListener about resource change...

Comment: You could have each editor listen for the events (i.e. add listener in unit method and remove when the editor is disposed).

Comment: the last suggestion sounds pretty "ugly". i want to do things as simple as they done for ITextEditor (refer to description)

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no higher level support for resource change notifications in GEF. You will have to rely on resource listener.